# PHP get 2nd element from foreach

Tags: php

I have this program it has 3 elements in array
and it prints 3/6/9/12 elements and so on
the problem is, I just want to get the 2nd element from array

so I have this code

```
$arr= array("a1", "a2", "a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3");
```

I want to get the value of a2 b2 and c2 but the problem is if it has like more than 9 over there like 12 or more.

By the way I am using for each

```
foreach($arr as $result){
    echo $result;
}
```

thanks in advance for helping

Update:
My expected output will be a2 b2 c2 and if theres d2 then it will output d2 and so on.

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please post a sample of expected output.

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $i => $result) ...`, then test with a minimum of math whether `$i` is a "second element"…

Comment: So you don't want just every other element, you want the second element according to some idea of elements being in a group (like beginning with the same letter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$result) {
    if (($key - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

That may do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is the one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply:

```
echo $arr[1];
```

You don't need any foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop, and increment the index variable to 3:

```
$arr = array("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3");

for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($arr) ; $idx += 3) {
   echo $arr[$idx] ;
}
```

Outputs:

```
a2
b2
c3
```

Comment: There is no need to loop over all elements, you can just get the values you want using `for`.

Comment: Best answer imho